# loading chunks of large text files from DB

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql, database-design, large-files

So, as the topic says - i need to serve chunks of multiple large text files loaded in DB. The files would be anywhere from `100` lines to `10.000.000` lines. i would serve it to multiple instances of processing script in chunks of 10/50/100 lines. Question is - what is the proper **way to store and serve them?** assuming there could be hundreds of such files.

**What DB and possible additional tools is the best choice?** `MongoDB + GridFS`? or there is an efficient way to serve them in such small chunks in case if i store them as `BLOB` in `PostgreSQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go for a relational database, I would store the files line by line in a table. That way it is easy to fetch lines:

```
SELECT line FROM documents
WHERE docname = 'mydoc'
  AND line_nr > 100
ORDER BY line_nr
FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

A b-tree index on `(docname, line_nr)` would make the query very efficient.

If you want to keep the table from getting too large, use range partitioning on `docname`.

Comment: a single table with all docs might have billions of records in such case. i guess navigating them simultaneously from dozens of clients would overload the DB quite a lot?

Comment: in addition: if using `b-tree` index does solve the navigation problem, what about requests without the use of it? for example `DELETE * WHERE docname = 'mydoc'`. i don't need to do that often or from multiple instances, but will it it be executed in reasonable time on a table with few billion records?

Comment: Yes, the `DELETE` would be efficient. You can either optimize for size or speed, and I thought you are interested in speed. Use range partitioning with `docname` if you want to reduce table size.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot of advise! so, in case of speed optimisation, the most efficient would be to keep it in one table with billions of records?

Comment: In my opinion, yes.